# Not sure why this happens to my inline-block elements

Tags: html, css, display

I am quite new to CSS and in the following code, my plan was to create 3 div elements and style them. Here is my code:

My codes:

```css
.box {
  background: orange;
  width: 30%;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 1%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">

    </div>
    <div class="box">

    </div>
    <div class="box">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

With just the code above the result is what I want

However, as soon as I try to add some text inside my div elements within the HTML the boxes go out of alignment:

[image]

Can someone explain the reason behind this? And tell me how to fix this? I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top` `.box`

```
vertical-align:top;
```

```css
.box {
  background: orange;
  width: 30%;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 1%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box">
        fhgf
      </div>
      <div class="box">

      </div>
      <div class="box">

      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Hey, man thanks for this. This actually worked but could you explain why the issue was happening in the first place? Like why do I need to use this?

Answer (score 1):

I just use the `grid box` to handle your problem and also you can use `flex box` instead

```css
  .container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.box {
  background: orange;
  width: 90%;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 1%;
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      hello
    </div>
    <div class="box">

    </div>
    <div class="box">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you man, I wanted to know the issue with my own code as a learning purpose but still thanks for this!

Comment: an issue was listed in the first once and I show you the other way of handle that error and if you find it is help you vote it otherwise downvote

Answer (score -1):

Try this at the beginning of your css file:

```
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: This didn't fix it as my div elements don't have margins/paddings etc.